# Prestashop: Creating a custom page for my module

Tags: module, prestashop

I looking for code which can create a custom page. The code must include all hooks and I should moderate the "home" hook and put my content there...

Anything is helpful - sample code for example, tutorials, documentations or something.

Best regards,

George!

Comment: Please be more explicit, I don't see what you mean...

Comment: I want to make a page with info for my module example: http://domain.com/myPrestaShopPage.php . The page must include all hooks and their items but in "home" hook must be my content :)

Answer (score 6):

Edit: 
**The standard way (for PS1.5 & PS1.6) is to [make a controller](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Embeddingatemplateinthetheme)**

Another way **(not recommended)** is to make a file like this wher you include the header/your content/the footer

```
<?php 
    global $smarty; 
    include( '../../config/config.inc.php' ); 
    include( '../../header.php' ); 

    $smarty->display( dirname(__FILE__) . '/mymodule_page.tpl' ); 

    include( '../../footer.php' ); 
?>
```

what you need to do  is save this file in you module folder like `newcustompage.php`
and then make some link in your .tpl point to it
example:

```
<a href="{$modules_dir}yourmodulefolder/newcustompage.php">Click this!</a>
```

[Prestashop Developer Guide](http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/1409083/PrestaShop-Developer-Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Try look at:
How to create a custom page -> http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/52650-how-to-add-a-custom-page/

How to create hooks in your page -> http://www.smaizys.com/prestashop/how-to-create-custom-prestashop-hook/

I hope this helps you. Kind regards