# Prestashop 1.5 Cookie content

Tags: cookies, prestashop

I need to display prestashop customer ID in an external PHP page.

In the official documentation http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Diving+into+PrestaShop+Core+development)

I found the php code:

*If you need to access the PrestaShop cookie from non-PrestaShop code, you can use this code:*

```
    include_once('path_to_prestashop/config/config.inc.php');
    include_once('path_to_prestashop/config/settings.inc.php');
    include_once('path_to_prestashop/classes/Cookie.php');
    $cookie = new Cookie('ps'); // Use "psAdmin" to read an employee's cookie.
```

So i tryed:

```
include_once('config/config.inc.php');
include_once('config/settings.inc.php');
include_once('classes/Cookie.php');
$cookie = new Cookie('ps'); 
$id_client = $cookie->id_customer;
echo $id_client;
```

But nothing is displayed, I tried other tokens, only "date_add" works

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
global $smarty;
global $cookie;
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');

$cookie = new Cookie('ps'); 
$id_client = $cookie->id_customer;
echo $id_client;

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php');
```

I tested it myself. Everything including id and firstname works. It seems you should not include classes/Cookie.php file. Instead, replace it with `global $cookie` Make sure to change the directory of the included files.

Comment: Also checkout this great reference [custom page for module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451490/prestashop-creating-a-custom-page-for-my-module)

Comment: what is your version? I tried copy/paste your code, it still doesn't work; I use v 1.5.4.0

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to specify my version. I use v 1.4.9.0. I don't think there should be a difference though. **Do you at least see the header/footer??** If you don't even see the header, you specified the directory wrongly. The code above is for when the external php file is in the root of Prestashop (i.e. directory with product.php, category.php, etc)

Comment: No I don't see, but paths seems to be good:

Warning: File ***/httpdocs/header.php is deprecated
in ***/httpdocs/classes/Tools.php on line 1843 Warning: Function displayHeader() is deprecated in ***/httpdocs/header.php on line 39
in ***/httpdocs/classes/Tools.php on line 1843 Warning: File ***/httpdocs/footer.php is deprecated
in ***/httpdocs/classes/Tools.php on line 1843 Warning: Function displayFooter() is deprecated in ***/httpdocs/footer.php on line 39
in ***/httpdocs/classes/Tools.php on line 1843

Comment: Hey Mael, it turns out Prestashop 1.5 is drastically different from 1.4 and needs a controller for each custom page. Check out this link [Create a custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336006/create-custom-page-in-prestashop-1-5-3)

Comment: I usd this scripts, that is working like charm! global $smarty;
global $cookie;
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');


    class GetidControllerCore extends FrontController
    {

        public function initContent()
        {
            parent::initContent();
            global $cookie;
            $cookie->id_customer;
            $customer=$this->context->customer->id;
        }

    }
//print_r($customer);
$id_cust = $customer->id;

Comment: Thanks for posting a better solution! Just a few things:
1) `global $cookie` is defined twice in your code
2) It should be `$customer=$this->context->customer`